# How can I convert these perl regex to python

Tags: python, regex, perl

I am trying to convert a perl script to python and I am hung up on the regex statements.

Perl Script:

```
open NICKNAME, $NICKNAMEFILE or die "$NICKNAMEFILE: $!";
<NICKNAME> =~ /.+[.].+[.](.+)/;
my $project = $1;
$struct{'project'} = $project;
close NICKNAME;

open KEYFILE, $KEYHASHFILE or die "$KEYHASHFILE: $!";
<KEY> =~ /^([-\w\d]+)$/;
my $key = $1;
$struct{'key'} = $key;
close KEYFILE;
```

Python:

```
nickname = open(NICKNAMEFILE, "r")
project = re.search(#something)
struct['project'] = project
nickname.close()

keyfile = open(KEYHASHFILE, "r")
key = re.search(#something)
struct['key'] = key
keyfile.close()
```

Comment: `#something = r'.+[.].+[.](.+)'`

Comment: Can you explain what it actually means? Is it looking for any number of decimals in a string?

Comment: I just translated the regex definition from Perl to Python.

Comment: /.+[.].+[.](.+)/ is looking for 'any character' (the .) at least once (the +), followed by a literal . followed by the same again (at least one of any character followed by a dot), then it looks for at least one of any character but records the value in $1 for later. The second one is looking for any alphanumeric character, and '-', at least once, and that no other characters are in the string. It also stores the result in $1

Comment: A bunch of characters followed by a dot followed by a bunch more characters followed by another dot followed by another bunch of characters which are captured. I strongly suspect the pattern actually needs to be anchored, and, also you probably should study more before attempting to do. Also, the script is not checking if the matches succeed, neither is your translated code, and that way lies destruction and catastrophe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression syntax is the same for Python and Perl. Your question is more "what does this regular expression search for."

Referencing the Python regular expression library, I can deduce the following (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
r'.+[.].+[.](.+)'
```

Is searching for something of the form

```
(one or more character).(one or more character).(one or more character)
```

And this one:

```
r'^([-\w\d]+)$'
```

Is searching for something of the form

```
a string starting with any number of letters A-Z/a-z or number 0-9 and no special characters
```